# Ubuntu 22.04 NIC problem

Tags: networking, drivers, hp, realtek

I have a Realtek rtl8822ce NIC in my HP 250 g9 that I use also on Windows sometimes.Every 10/20 minutes the wifi network disconnects and I have to disable and enable again wifi network. I made an .sh shell script which does this for me. I have tried a lot of solutions, but none of them worked for me.

EDIT: I have costantly energy saving mode because I need my laptop for 6 hours a day with no charger.

Comment: Look at the network logs with the terminal command: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl NetworkManager service`. Also do: `service NetworkManager status` and `service --status-all`.

Comment: I've written a bash script to help with this: `https://github.com/waltinator/net-o-matic` It watches the connection, and when the connection drops, does a user-specified thing to try to reconnect or do something else.

Comment: How are you controlling the wifi connection? using iw, netplan, NetworkManager, or old school ifupdown?  I would suggest you have a look at your systemd, I suspect you have two differnt systems trying to control the wifi, you bring it up using one of the system, and the other system, trys to recover the connection, with a differnt config, after x minutes.    Also check what is in the config of wpa_supplicant, this controls the auth for wifi's